# Did blockchain.com stold my Bitcoins?

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

Some 5 years ago I stored some Bitcoins on Blockchain.info, I remembered a few days that I still had a tiny amount left which would be worth something today, around 0.20 BTC in total which makes around $9,500+ with the currents Bitcoin value.

I decided to check my wallet which I did not log in for years. For my surprise the wallet address did not exist, and I was redirected to blockchain.com instead of .info

The login had an input to use the wallet ID, which I did. It then emailed me for authentication which I confirmed, it then asked for my second factor authentication which I entered but for my surprise it then asked me for a second password (besides my normal one). I had a second password stored, but that was only used while spending bitcoins, it was a spending password. I entered that, and it said incorrect, then again, and again and again. I tried multiple times with errors, this was already strange since they never asked this before on login, finally for some reason the page was blank and in a surprise, I was finally logged into my account.

But bigger was my surprise when by BTC balance was 0. Instead, I had around $147 something in the account and my balance is now showing as Bitcoin Cash. Bitcoin Cash did not even exist back in 2017, I never received any email from them about any conversion ever, or I would have moved by balance out. In fact, I don't remember receiving any email from them in years about anything.

I contacted their support, 2 days later no reply. No explanation.

Did they just steal my bitcoins, or I'm missing something here? I found another person here on Stack Exchange that asked the same thing. Is blockchain.com a legit company or are they fraudsters stealing people's Bitcoins?

Comment: When did your BTC balance become zero? You didn't have to do anything to get bitcoin cash, it happened automatically because bitcoin cash began with the same state the bitcoin blockchain had.

Comment: Since we have no insight into the internal processes of blockchain.com nor the make-up of your system, we cannot determine how your wallet was compromised. As we cannot objectively answer your question as it's asked, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

you should check in history/activity when your btc was sold.

Btc forked to bch and bchscv so your btc became all 3.

if you had 0.2btc then you also have 0.2 bch (at current price that is about the amount you mention)

If you dont recall selling the BTC it is also possible to see what IP address was accessing your account.

Comment: The account was restricted with everything, including 2FA. The balance had 0 BTC but 0.20+ BCH, BCH had no transactions. Bitcoin had the transactions I made years back, nothing after that time.